# Monero wallet RPC don't work

Tags: monero-wallet-rpc

I have a huge problem with the RPC wallet.
It starts ok, tried - - log-level 4 and all goes OK but it does not bind on the RPC port and I cannot send RPC commands. It just stops at Starting RPC server. 
I am trying to setup a pool and the pool just says faill at contacting walletd with the wallet response being {}

Comment: Could you share use the log, after you censored sensitive information?

Comment: Also, which command did you execute to start `monero-wallet-rpc`

Comment: You're not binding on 127.0.0.1, are you ?

Answer (score 0):

It can take a while to fully start up, especially on lower end machines.

Answer (score 0):

Poor design decision, I would have designed monero that way that RPC starts up regardless of anything, and returns 'busy'.

But unfortunately RPC depends on many conditions. (network, being synced etc.)
You can see it logs it does block syncs even when it seems to hang.

It would make designing anything on top of monero much easier.

Not sure how the GUI overcome this.